# How to pass data to component after action dispatched to Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, flux

I'm using Vuex to try manage application-level data. I fetch the data, using axios, then propogate that data to data variables in a component. Nothing complicated.

My store looks like this

```js
// store.js
// appropriate imports and such

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      var: []
    },
    actions:{
      getData(context){
        axios.get('/endpoint').then(function(response){
          context.state.var = res.data.value1;
          console.log("action in store.js run");

//appropriate brackets,etc below
```

I then dispatch this action in my app.js

```js
//appropriate imports and such above

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store: store,
    created() {
      this.$store.dispatch('getRightSidebar')
      console.log("action dispatched")
    }
});
```

I use the *created lifecycle hook* to ensure this action gets dispatched **before** the component is mounted. Surely, at this point **two** messages should be logged to the console. One message from the created lifestyle hook and another from the actual action being dispatched. However, when I run the application only the former message is logged. Surely, when the action is dispacthed, the actual method/request me be called/executed.

Now, when I print the values of the state variables, from within the mounted lifecycle hook of the component, they're undefined. However, if I print the state it logs the object with the appropriate data

```js
///component.js

mounted() {
  console.log("component mounted")
  console.log(this.$store.state.var) // undefined
  console.log(this.$store.state) // Obeject with the appropriate data
}
```

So on one hand it seems to dispatch the action, but when I try to access individual objects from the state, it craps itself. Is there something wrong with the way I'm trying to access objects within the state?

Comment: Do you want to "block" any rendering until the data is retrieved? If not, I think the answer by @ilya-salmasov would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to "wait" for `getData` promise to resolve

when created() hook runs there can be no data

```js
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      var: []
    },
    actions:{
       getRightSidebar(context){
        // must return Promise to subscribe to it!
        return axios.get('/endpoint').then(function(response){
          context.state.var = res.data.value1;
          console.log("action in store.js run");
```

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store: store,
    data: {
      isLoading: true
    },
    async mounted() {
      await this.$store.dispatch('getRightSidebar')
      // after this there is gonna be some data 
      this.isLoading = false
    }
})
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if='isLoading'>loading...</div>
    <div v-else>{{$store.state.yourvariable}}</div>
 </div>
</template>
```